# ant macrodefs and element naming

Tags: ant, macrodef

I have a macrodef with a an element called "libs"

```
<macrodef name="deploy-libs">
    <element name="libs"/>
    <sequential>
        <copy todir="${glassfish.home}/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib">              
            <fileset dir="${lib}">
                <libs/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

which is then invoked as

```
<deploy-libs>
    <libs>
        <include name="mysql-connector-*.jar"/>
        <include name="junit-*.jar" />
        <!-- .... -->
    </libs>
</deploy-libs>
```

I then have another macrodef which calls several macrodefs including "deploy-libs". It would be nice if this macrodef had an element "libs" too but:

```
<macrodef name="init-glassfish">
    <element name="libs"/>
    <sequential>

        <!-- other stuff -->

        <deploy-libs>
            <libs>
                <libs/>
            </libs>
        </deploy-libs>

        <!-- other stuff -->

    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

is obviously not working (because of `<libs><libs/></libs>`):

```
Commons/ant-glassfish-server.xml:116: unsupported element include
```

A solution could be to name the element in "init-glassfish" in a different way:

```
<macrodef name="init-glassfish">
    <element name="libraries"/>
    <sequential>

        <!-- other stuff -->

        <deploy-libs>
            <libs>
                <libraries/>
            </libs>
        </deploy-libs>

        <!-- other stuff -->

    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Is there a way to have the element to be named in the same way for both macrodefs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my question which solves the original problem using a path id

```
<macrodef name="deploy-libs">

    <attribute name="libraries-path-refid"/>

    <sequential>
         <copy todir="${glassfish.home}/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib">             
            <path refid="@{libraries-path-refid}"/>
         </copy>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Now this does not solve the issue with the *nested* elements tags but (XY problem) solves the practical issue. It would be still be nice to know if something similar to the original question is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the solution is wrapping additional `<libs>` elements around in the original call depending on how deep the macros nest. Of course this is a horrible solution because it requires that the macro nesting depth is known on invocation, e.g.:

```
<deploy-libs>
  <libs>
    <libs>
      <include name="mysql-connector-*.jar"/>
      <include name="junit-*.jar" />
      <!-- .... -->
    </libs>
  </libs>
</deploy-libs>
```

[Ant bug 29153](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29153) addressing this problem was unfortunately resolved as *invalid* :(.